# Drupal 7 Feeds Module not working

Tags: drupal-7

I have installed the Drupal 7 feeds module and created an Importer.

I can display the Stand-alone form, add a file but the upload / parse page just displays the message "Importing..." It doesn't do much else and does not import into a selected content type. No errors are displayed.

Any ideas?

// Importer below /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
$feeds_importer = new stdClass();
$feeds_importer->disabled = FALSE; 

$feeds_importer->api_version = 1;
$feeds_importer->id = 'shop_ids';
$feeds_importer->config = array(
    'name' => 'Shop IDs',
    'description' => 'Import a CSV file which feeds into Shop ID node type',
    'fetcher' => array(
    'plugin_key' => 'FeedsFileFetcher',
    'config' => array(
    'allowed_extensions' => 'txt csv tsv xml opml',
    'direct' => 0,
    'directory' => 'public://feeds',
    'allowed_schemes' => array(
    'public' => 'public',
    'private' => 'private',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'parser' => array(
  'plugin_key' => 'FeedsCSVParser',
  'config' => array(
  'delimiter' => ',',
  'no_headers' => 1,
  ),
 ),
  'processor' => array(
  'plugin_key' => 'FeedsNodeProcessor',
  'config' => array(
  'expire' => '-1',
  'author' => 0,
  'authorize' => 1,
  'mappings' => array(
    0 => array(
      'source' => '\'0\'',
      'target' => 'title',
      'unique' => 1,
    ),
    1 => array(
      'source' => '\'1\'',
      'target' => 'body',
      'unique' => FALSE,
    ),
  ),
  'update_existing' => '1',
  'input_format' => 'plain_text',
  'skip_hash_check' => 0,
  'bundle' => 'shop_ids',
  ),
  ),
  'content_type' => '',
  'update' => 0,
  'import_period' => '-1',
  'expire_period' => 3600,
  'import_on_create' => 1,
  'process_in_background' => 0,
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was an error with batch.js

JQuery causing function error

fix was to add ; to beginning of code.

```
;(function ($) {
```

and add the (jQuery); to the end of the file...

```
})(jQuery);
```